# Which value of $y$ I should take?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, absolute-value

There are points in complex space. Among these points, there are

$z_{B} = \sqrt{3} - i$

$z_{C} = i$

$z_{E} = -\sqrt{3} - i$

**The question says:** Find $z_{H}$ where $\overrightarrow{HC}.\overrightarrow{EB} = 0$ and $||\overrightarrow{HC}|| = 3$

**My solution:**

So I did dot product between the two vectors $\overrightarrow{HC}$ and $\overrightarrow{EB}$

I found that $x_{H} = 0$

Then to find $y_{H}$:

||$\overrightarrow{HC}|| = 3$ means

$\sqrt{(y_{H} - 1)^{2}} = 3$

Here is the thing, that means it's absolute value

So

$\sqrt{(y_{H} - 1)^{2}} = \begin{cases}
 & \text{ } 3 \\ 
OR
 & \text{} - 3
\end{cases}$

That means $y_{H}$ is either $4$ or $-2$

So which value I take here?

Comment: Both solutions are valid

Comment: @Ripi2 The book's solution takes $-4$ though and I don't understand why.

Comment: Seems an error in your book. Both $(0+4i)$ and $(0-2i)$ solutions are perpendicular to the horizontal $EB$ and they HC norms are 3.

Comment: @Ripi2 That's what I thought. I was so confused because neither solutions provide -4, it seems an error like you said. Well, thank you for confirmation anyway!